# How do I call an object method from my Country class?

Tags: java, jdbc

My objective is to call my object method getId from my Country class and also I need to insert a loop over my country list before my readCountryLanguages sql statement.

```
public class ReadCountryDB {
private static final String DB_NAME = "Countries";
private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://cisdbss.***.***/" + DB_NAME;
private static final String COUNTRY_TABLE_NAME = "COUNTRY";
private static final String USERNAME = "233jExample";
private static final String PASSWORD = "tnedutsj332";

private List<Country> countries;


/**
 * Create a ReadCountryDB object
 * Read from the Country database and populate the countries list
 */
public ReadCountryDB() {
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement sqlStatement = null;

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        sqlStatement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

        countries = readCountries(sqlStatement);
        readCountryLanguages(sqlStatement, countries);//<--added 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close(sqlStatement);
        close(connection);
    }
}

/**
 * Read country info from the Country table
 * 
 * @param sqlStatement
 * @return the list of countries read
 * @throws SQLException
 */


private List<Country> readCountries(Statement sqlStatement) throws SQLException {
    List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();
    ResultSet resultSet = sqlStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + COUNTRY_TABLE_NAME);
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        countries.add(new Country(resultSet.getInt("Id"),
                                  resultSet.getString("Name"),
                                  resultSet.getLong("Population"),
                                  resultSet.getDouble("MedianAge")));

    }
    return countries;

 }
//add country list loop here
  private List<String> readCountryLanguages(Statement sqlStatement, List<Country>countries) throws SQLException {
    List<String> languages = new ArrayList<>();
    ResultSet resultSet = sqlStatement.executeQuery("SELECT language FROM COUNTRY_LANGUAGE");
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        String language = new String(resultSet.getString("Languages"));
        int getId = new getId();//call getId method here

    }
    return languages;
}




/**
 * Close the given statement, eat any errors
 * 
 * @param sqlStatement
 */
private void close(Statement sqlStatement) {
    if (sqlStatement != null) {
        try {
            sqlStatement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Close the given connection, eat any errors.
 * 
 * @param connection
 */
private void close(Connection connection) {
    if (connection != null) {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @return list of countries read from the country database
 */
public List<Country> getCountries() {
    return countries;
}
```

} Here is the Country class with object method I trying to call.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Country {
private int id;
private String name;
private long population;
private double medianAge;
private static List<String> languages;


/**
 * Create a Country object with the given properties
 */
public Country(int id, String name, long population, double medianAge) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.population = population;
    this.medianAge = medianAge;
    Country.languages = new ArrayList<>();      
}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public long getPopulation() {
    return population;
}

public double getMedianAge() {
    return medianAge;
}

public void addLanguage (String language) {
    languages.add(language);
}

public List<String> getLanguages() {
    return languages;
}



 }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to ask, can you clarify?

Comment: I am trying to call the object method 'getId' in the Country Class and also I need to create a  loop over my country list before my readCountryLanguages sql statement.

Comment: to call the getId() you need a reference of the country class, you can use your list like this countries.get(i).getId(); but not sure what are you trying to do here, do you want to set the language of each country in countries ?

Comment: Are you trying to call it in the class (object itself, somewhere in Country.java), or are you trying to call it elsewhere, like in ReadCountryDB.java?

Comment: @DoubleMa yes exactly!

Comment: @Water I'm trying to call the getId method from the Country class.

Comment: @wisenhiemer sorry but you didn't really answer my question. "From the Country class" is ambigious, since I don't know if you're new to Java (which it looks like based on what you're asking), or if you literally mean you want to call the method getId() somewhere inside the object itself inside the file Country.java).

Comment: @Water Apologies, I am new to java and I am trying to call the method getId from ReadCountryDB.java.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like that:

```
private void readCountryLanguages(Statement sqlStatement, List<Country> countries) throws SQLException {
    for (Country country : countries) {
        ResultSet resultSet = sqlStatement.executeQuery("SELECT language FROM COUNTRY_LANGUAGE WHERE country_id=" + country.getId());
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            //todo here for example:
            String[] langs = ....;' //get the langs from the resultSet (depending on your database)
            for(String lang : langs){
                country.addLanguage(lang);
            }

        }
        resultSet.close();
    }
}
```

then you can get the languages by calling your function

```
List<String> languages = yourCountry.getLanguages();
```